# Dragging and dropping dynamically added edit text views

Tags: android, drag-and-drop, android-edittext

I have relative layout which consists of a button

When I press this button it adds the new custom edittext that I have created to the relative layout

These custom edit text can be dragged and dropped anywhere in the layout. This part of the code works fine.

The problem is ::
When I add the first custom edit text and reposition it by dragging it and adding another custom edittext the app works weird not as expected( the two custom edittext overlap each other).

For a better understanding of my problem watch this [video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrhOOD5lzWOVm5idVNkbXVodWs/view?usp=drivesdk)

Instead of custom edit text I have tried the same code with textviews and its working fine you can watch this video for the textviews sample[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwrhOOD5lzWOMl9aY1ZwdmUtRlk/view?usp=drivesdk)

Maybe it's due to the setting of on long click listener to my custom edit text in the onclick listener of the button

**my main activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{


TextView X, Y;

RelativeLayout dropLayout;
LayoutParams params;
Button addText;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    dropLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.ondraglayout);  
    dropLayout.setOnDragListener(new MyDragListener());
     addText = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
    addText.setOnClickListener(new MyButtonClickListener());



    X=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.xvalue);
    Y=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.yvalue);


    dropLayout.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View p1, MotionEvent event)
            {
                switch(event.getAction()){
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        int x=(int) event.getX();
                        int y=(int) event.getY();
                        X.setText("x coord is " + x);
                        Y.setText("y coord is " + y);
                        break;

                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        x=(int) event.getX();
                        y=(int) event.getY();
                        X.setText("x coord is " + x);
                        Y.setText("y coord is " + y);
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }


    });
}




   }
```

**my clicklistener**

```
public class MyButtonClickListener implements OnClickListener
 {

@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{
    ViewGroup relativeParent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
    CustomEdittext edttxt = new CustomEdittext(v.getContext());
    relativeParent.addView(edttxt);
    edttxt.setOnLongClickListener(new MyLongClickListener());

}

  }
```

** MyLongClickListner **

```
public class MyLongClickListner implements OnLongClickListener
 {

@Override
public boolean onLongClick(View v)
{

    ClipData dragdata = ClipData.newPlainText("","");

    View.DragShadowBuilder shdwbldr = new View.DragShadowBuilder(v);

    v.startDrag(dragdata, shdwbldr, v, 0);
    v.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);

    return true;
}

   }
```

**my draglistener**

```
public class MyDragListener implements OnDragListener
 {

private LayoutParams params;

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event)
{
    View view = (View) event.getLocalState();


    switch(event.getAction())
    {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

            params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();  
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            int x = (int) event.getX();
            int y = (int) event.getY();

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION  :
            x=  (int) event.getX();
            y =  (int) event.getY();
            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED   :

            break;

        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

            x = (int) event.getX();
            y = (int) event.getY();
            params.leftMargin = x;
            params.topMargin = y;

            view.setLayoutParams(params);
            view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            break;
        default: break;
    }
    return true;
}


 }
```

**my custom edit text**

```
public class CustomEdittext extends EditText
 {

Paint paint;

public CustomEdittext(Context context){
    super(context);
    init();


}

public CustomEdittext(Context context, AttributeSet attr){
    super(context, attr);

    init();

}   


public void init(){
    paint = new Paint();

    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    paint.setStrokeWidth(4);
    paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);




}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas)
{

    super.onDraw(canvas);

    canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
}


  }
```

**my main xml**

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#CDC2C0"
android:id="@+id/ondraglayout">



<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:id="@+id/yvalue"/>

<TextView
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/yvalue"
    android:id="@+id/xvalue"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="T"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:id="@+id/mainButton1"/>

  </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Can we see your xml as well, i think the line: 
ViewGroup relativeParent = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();

is returning the wrong parent, maybe you have nested Relative Layouts, am just guessing this. Paste your xml, so that we have a better idea.

Comment: @vibhor_shri posted my xml file also ,,please have a look

Comment: Also, kindly try this with a Linear Layout as a parent, with Vertical Orientation. The reason i say this, is because Relative Layouts generally need positioning for their children, relative to one another. Like, layout_above, layout_below, etc. The reason for the overlap could be that although both layouts are getting added, but they add on top of each other. With a vertical linear layout, this will not happen. But am not very sure about this, because your code works well with Text Views. But give it a try once please.

Comment: @vibhor_shri yup i ll try and let you know

Comment: @vibhor_shri  but the problem with  linear layouts is either the child views get vertically stacked or horizontally,,,two view cannot be placed side by side,,,that is why i used relativelayout,,,,and it works fine with text views,,,maybe because no listeners were set to textviews

Comment: No, we can place views next to each other even in linear layouts, but there would be a limit as to how many of them can be placed next to each other, i'll try and come up with a solution for the problem. Give me some time, just a quick question. What versions are you targeting, min sdk?

Comment: @vibhor_shri i am target android 4.1 and above,,,and thank you very much for taking up to solve my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, after some research i got this working. Here is the implementation, made a few changes from your initial approach.

Firstly, i've changed you xml to some extent.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ondraglayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#CDC2C0"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/dropLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/xvalue">

    </RelativeLayout>


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/yvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xvalue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@id/yvalue"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/mainButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="T" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I hope it is fine.

Secondly, as you can see in the xml, another empty layout has been added. The dropLayout is where we will drop the items. In your activity, reference this layout, then set the drag listener on it.

```
dropLayoutNew.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
dropLayoutNew.setOnTouchListener(otl);
```

The on touch listener is below, i commented out your implementation:

```
private View.OnTouchListener otl = new View.OnTouchListener() {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return true; // the listener has consumed the event
    }
};
```

This is in the same activity, ie the MainActivity. Now, as for the last change i've made. I have created the on drag listener within the MainActivity itself, because i was somehow not able to debug that portion of code,the drag listener from another class(separate issue). So, for the drag listener, paste the below code in your MainActivity.

```
View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
        View view = (View) event.getLocalState();
        ViewGroup vg = (ViewGroup) v.getParent();
        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout)vg.findViewById(R.id.dropLayout);


        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:

                params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();


                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
                int x = (int) event.getX();
                int y = (int) event.getY();

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_LOCATION:
                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:

                break;

            case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                int childCountDropped = rl.getChildCount();
                System.out.println("Child Count of Views::::::Dropped" + childCountDropped);

                x = (int) event.getX();
                y = (int) event.getY();
                params.leftMargin = x;
                params.topMargin =  y;

                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
};
```

You can see some code added, but it does not change ur implementation. I wanted to check number of child items in the Relative Layout. I initially thought that it will give me a clear idea about the target layout(where items are being dropped). None the less, this is now working as you wanted. I checked it on a nexus 5 emulator, running 6.0. Do check it for other versions as well.

Conclusion: I am not sure as to why the drag listener was not working when referenced from another class, but none the less, it is working as you wanted now. The onTouchListener, again, you had a different implementation from mine. Maybe we will have to look into some more details on that. The main diff i did was to change the drop layout, you were doing it on the parent, i did it on another child. Rest mostly its the same. I would recommend to try out some other implementation as well, share with us the result.

I hope this code helps, let me know if this does not work.

Comment: Bro thank you for taking your time and getting a solution I am currently outside but will soon test your code and let you know if its working as I wanted again thank you very much

Comment: Thanks bro working fine,,,,thank you very much,,,,,i would like to help you back if you have any problem

Comment: Bro just found this problem,,,when two views are overlapped the overlapping view disaapears,,,what to do about this???

Comment: @user5894647, ur welcome buddy. For when the views overlap, i guess u might only want to show one of them? right? 'll get on this, after tomorrow....

Comment: i want to show them both or restrict one from overlapping another

Comment: @user5894647, no i was not able to find a suitable solution for it, maybe you can make the view as invisible when dropping coordinates are same. try with this approach.